# Django - Is it possible to translate only some of the models (admin forms)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-i18n

Say that you have a django admin site with the common Users / Groups models, along some other models that you want to leave untranslated, yet some specific forms that need to be translated to another pre-defined language, so it can be easy to use them.

Think Hebrew/Arabic:
I have found a easy ways to translate the field names, and even the "rtl.css" for translating my forms *partially*. Yet the titles are still in English, but are poised on the right of the screen.

The docs, and a number of examples out there shows, that there is good support when it comes to translating the whole admin site (by setting the language on the whole site via settings), yet I could not find how to set the language specifically to one/some forms, which seems a reasonable request.

Answer (score 0):

That was much easier then anticipated...

copy rtl.css from the django repository to your static/

Then in any ModelAdmin you want to work RTL just add:

```
class Media:
    css = {'all': ('project_name_folder/css/rtl.css',)}

def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
    translation.activate('he') # 'he' for hebrew
    return super().render_change_form(request, context, add, change,         
    translation.activate('en') # go back to english/LTR for other views
```

form_url, obj)

And you're good to go. This will affect only the admin of the model that was overriden.